# In Qt, how to perform hide operation in smoother way?

Tags: qt, animation, widget, qt4

In Qt, whenever a widget is set to hide, I want to perform the action in smooth way.

Is there any standard function for that?

Comment: You mean like an animation?

Comment: When you need animations and smooth graphics, you should consider using QML rather than "oldschool" widgets.

Answer (score 1):

Heres example for show and hide button:

```
void MainWindow::hideButton(){
    QGraphicsOpacityEffect* fade_effect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);
    ui->pushButton->setGraphicsEffect(fade_effect);
    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(fade_effect, "opacity");
    animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InOutQuad);
    animation->setDuration(5000);
    animation->setStartValue(1);
    animation->setEndValue(0.01);
    animation->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}

void MainWindow::showButton(){
    QGraphicsOpacityEffect* fade_effect = new QGraphicsOpacityEffect(this);
    ui->pushButton->setGraphicsEffect(fade_effect);
    QPropertyAnimation *animation = new QPropertyAnimation(fade_effect, "opacity");
    animation->setEasingCurve(QEasingCurve::InOutQuad);
    animation->setDuration(5000);
    animation->setStartValue(0.01);
    animation->setEndValue(1.0);
    animation->start(QPropertyAnimation::DeleteWhenStopped);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [animation framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/animation-overview.html) and set the geometry to `0,0` for the height and width, when you restore it just set it back to the previous height and width value. There's various easing effects in there for you to use as you do it, and a few code examples.